# Laravel Model Factory Error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel-5.1, faker

I'm trying to use a model factory to seed my database, but when I run it I get the error:

`Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`

Here is my code:

// TasksTableSeeder.php

```
factory(pams\Task::class, '2000', rand(1, 30))->create();
```

// ModelFactory.php

```
$factory->defineAs(pams\Task::class, '2000', function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
static $task_number = 01;
return [
    'task_number' => $task_number++,
    'ata_code' => '52-00-00',
    'time_estimate' => $faker->randomFloat($nbMaxDecimals = 2, $min = 0.25, $max = 50),
    'work_order_id' => '2000',
    'description' => $faker->text($maxNbChars = 75),
    'action' => '',
    'duplicate' => '0',
    'certified_by' => '1',
    'certified_date' => '2015-11-08',
    'status' => '1',
    'created_by' => '1',
    'modified_by' => '1',
    'created_at' => Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'updated_at' => Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    ];
});
```

I've tried removing all variables from the model factory and using constants, but that doesn't fix it. I've tried pulling the data from the `ModelFactory.php` and put it directly into the `TasksTableSeeder.php` and it does work, however I was using constants and no variables.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what 'id' it's talking about.

I'm running Laravel v5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. At one stage I had implemented a `BaseModel.php` model that automatically inserts the current users ID when creating or updating the model. The seeder fails because there isn't a current user, so I had to add a check to see if there was a user logged in first.

Here is the code:

```
static::creating(function($model)
    {
        if(Auth::user())
        {
            $model->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
            $model->modified_by = Auth::user()->id;
        }
        else
        {
            $model->created_by = '1';
            $model->modified_by = '1';
        }
    });

    static::updating(function($model)
    {   
        if(Auth::user())
        {
            $model->modified_by = Auth::user()->id;
        }
        else
        {
            $model->modified_by = '1';
        }
    });
```

It's not super pretty, but it gets the job done :)

Comment: It's not the best practice to use hard coded user id in your base model.

Answer (score 3):

Your `BaseModel` is not exactly appropriate as it will force you to create hacks in order to run something like a unit test. It will be better that you have a flag in the `BaseModel` that you test for true or false before setting `created_by` and `modified_by`.

Also there's no guarantee there will be `user_id` '1' at any point in time, unless you actually create that `User` in your factory first, before creating the `Task`.

A way to fix your current setup is have a protected field like `$enableAuthUpdates` which is set to false or true by default. Then you can override the field in any of your derived models such as your Task model to prevent the creating/updating events from running.

Also it's important to make sure your factory has an actual user it is working with and create it if it doesn't exist.